# How to open a url, without changing the orientation or fullscreen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, screen-orientation, html5-fullscreen

The user on my webpage clicks a button and the webpage (mobile chrome) goes into (i) full screen, and (ii) landscape mode.

Thereafter when the user clicks to open another url thru javascript, I want the new page to open in the same fullscreen and landscape mode. However, the page opens in a normal screen and portrait mode.

How can I achieve this. On way I think could be if I open all the pages (including the main page) in iframe? Is this doable? Are there better solutions for the same?

The relevant cod is:

```
function toggleFullScreen() { //For full screen
                  var doc = window.document;
                  var docEl = doc.documentElement;

                  var requestFullScreen = docEl.requestFullscreen || docEl.mozRequestFullScreen || docEl.webkitRequestFullScreen || docEl.msRequestFullscreen;
                  var cancelFullScreen = doc.exitFullscreen || doc.mozCancelFullScreen || doc.webkitExitFullscreen || doc.msExitFullscreen;

                  if(!doc.fullscreenElement && !doc.mozFullScreenElement && !doc.webkitFullscreenElement && !doc.msFullscreenElement) {
                    requestFullScreen.call(docEl);
                  }
                  else {
                    cancelFullScreen.call(doc);
                  }
                }

function start() { //on button click for fullscreen+orientation+openpage
        toggleFullScreen();
        screen.orientation.lock("landscape");
        window.open("https://gotrade.pro/?page_id=28", "_top"); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to load a new page via ajax and then replace the whole HTML tree with the loaded content:

document.documentElement.innerHTML = ajaxLoadedContent;

The HTML tag has to be cutted off from ajaxLoadedContent